# Model, year of fabrication, some details

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image]

Can anyone help me find more details about this bike? What's with the inscription on the handlebar? It has another one on the opposite side "3" with a laurels crown.
thanks guys!

Comment: You essentially provide no details except one closeup of a part that can be swapped aftermarket. You’re going to have to provide more photographs of the entire bike with details of the drivetrain etc

Comment: I am working on that, I just don't know yet how to do it.

Comment: Hmm, the cables should not run over the stem, this isn't pro-work. The bar tape looks like starting from the top of the bars. And the stem has most certainly been damaged by putting the bicycle upside down. scratching of the saddle could confirm this.

Comment: @MariusCiobanu as a low-rep/new user you can only post two photos.  Feel free to upload them to http://imgur.com/ and a mod can edit them into your question.

Comment: @MariusCiobanu  Please used Edit to add more information, else the question will get closed.

Comment: "unclear what you're asking for" is a bad classification, "not enough information" would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 4):

From your one photo, we can tell is its a road bike, probably painted black.
I think its been converted to single speed because there's a clearly visible downtube boss, with no lever in it.  So its fair to assume there's no decals or labels either

TL;DR you're completely out of luck.  Be mad at whoever painted it and removed the head tube and covered all markings.  You might be lucky and peel the paint off showing some kind of lettering, but that's unlikely to work.

---

Going on what we can see:

Quill stem and threadded fork means its probably older than the 90s or its a reproduction.

I can see a single pivot front caliper rim brake, but the cable appears to come up from the wrong side.  Writing visible is not mirrored, so that's an oddball caliper.  It may have been intended to sit behind the fork and someone's flipped it and moved to the conventional location.

The headtube seems awfully long, so that suggests its sized for a tall rider.

Its out of focus but I can see clipless pedals with a distinct triangular shape.  They may be Shimano 105 PD-1050 which date from the 90s, like this:

[image]

The bars are aluminium alloy 3T "Competizione" or possibly "Super Competizione" and date from the 90s.  Like [this ebay auction](https://www.ebay.com/itm/3ttt-Competizione-mod-vintage-alloy-handlebar-with-stem/222672548046)   They're nice but not rare.

[image]

The "3 with a laurels crown" is probably like this which is a 3T or TTT logo:

[image]

Comment: That's great detective work on a ridiculous question.

Comment: Those are not clipless pedals, the toe-clips and the straps are missing. I have a pair of these Shimano pedals dating from the late 80s. The toe-clips were made from black plastic and held by three screws, hence the holes at the front. And the bike seems to be British or at least meant to be ridden on the left side of the road since the front brake is connected to the right hand brake lever. Look at the routing of the cable housing!

Comment: @Carel Indeed.  I still think that caliper is backward or mirrored somehow.

Comment: @Criggie: Just went to check my bikes: The one of '37 vintage still has it's '50s Weinmann brakes and the rear one has the cable on the right looking from behind, while left is common today All the other front brakes have their cables right and rears are left. So this may not always have been a standard configuration.